# Cost-effective creation of a symmetric matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm fairly new to MATLAB and have a piece of code which creates a distance matrix. To be more precise, it creates a distance matrix D between points that lie on an undirected graph, such that Dij is the shortest path between the points on that graph. This matrix is obviously symmetric (because the graph is undirected) and the following is the code snippet that I use to create it:

```
D = zeros(size(data,1));
for i = 1:size(data, 1)
    for j = 1:size(data, 1)
        [D(i, j), ~, ~] = graphshortestpath(G, i, j, 'Directed', false);
    end
end
```

This is obviously very wasteful, since I'm not exploiting the symmetry of the matrix. Is there any way in which I can compute only the upper triangular part of the matrix and then somehow "append" the lower triangular part to it, such that I reduce my computations from n^2 to n^2 / 2?

Any help appreciated,

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Just think about the order of iteration, to figure out which triangle is reached first.

```
D = zeros(size(data,1));
for i = 1:size(data, 1)
    for j = 1:size(data, 1)
        if j > i
            [D(i, j), ~, ~] = graphshortestpath(G, i, j, 'Directed', false);
        else
            D(i, j) = D(j, i);
        end
    end
end
```

If diagonal elements aren't identically zero, you can use `if j >= i` instead.

Comment: I'll go for this one, because I find it to be the simplest way and the only overhead is a reference copy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For undirected and unweighted graph, an alternative way of computing Distance matrix

May help if u are trying to reduce your runtime. In the case of Matlab, most of the time, I find scanning entry by entry is slower. I am just guessing your purpose of asking the question, sorry if I am out of topic.

Given a Adjacency Matix ( G ), I would compute the distance matrix in following way,

Assumptions: 
 1. G is undirected & unweighted ( matrix filled with '0' and '1' ) 
 2. N is the order of the graph with G is of size N x N

```
function [D,connect]=genDistance(G,N)

D = G;
B = G;
connect = 0;
i=1;
while((~connect)&&(i<N-1))    % the maximum distance from one vert to another
    i = i + 1;                % is N-1
    B = B * G;                % G to the power of i
    D = D + i * (D==0&B>0);   % D==0 & B>0 the entries to be updated 
    connect = ( min(min(D)) )>0;  %check if D has zero entry
end
D ( eye(N) ) = 0 ; %clear diagonal entries
```

- (i,j) entry in "G power k" will give you the number of walks of
  length k from Vi to Vj in G
- in the end, connect will tell you whether the graph is connected

Comment: @yuk: Can I have a look at your test case? This method will only work on undirected and unweighted graph. This two assumptions will guarantee that G is symmetric and filled up with only '0' and '1'. This is kind of a special case.

Comment: Take my comment back. The result of your code is symmetrical for symmetrical matrix. It's just not in the same style as from `graphshortestpath` with 1s and `Inf`s for edges without connection. This is really the fastest method. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can generate indices for the lower part of the matrix `G` with

```
N = length(G);
[irow, icol] = find(tril(ones(N),-1));
```

Then you can loop through those indices:

```
D = zeros(size(G));
for i = 1:numel(irow)
   [D(irow(i), icol(i)] = graphshortestpath(G, irow(i), icol(i), 'Directed', false);
end
D = D + D';
```

---

Another option is to use ARRAYFUN with those indices and SQUAREFORM to convert the resulted vector into a square matrix:

```
D = arrayfun(@(x,y) graphshortestpath(G,x,y, 'Directed', false), irow, icol);
D = squareform(D);
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: @yuk Are you computing the diagonal elements?

Comment: @jucestain: When dealing with distance, diagonal elements should all be zero.

Comment: No. If it's undirected graph, I don't think they will be above 0. @Jason, I'm I correct?

Comment: @yuk: I think you're computing the Cartesian product of the rows and columns returned by `find`.  You want to instead iterate a pairwise list.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good catch on the Cartesian product.

Comment: @yuk You're second option is faster because your first option is iterating incorrectly. You should have a single loop with `for i = length(irow)` as per Ben's comment.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks, Found the error with the loop version. Time to go to bed. :)

Comment: Now this looks right, even if `find` is a very inefficient way to do it.  Using the structure should be much faster.

Comment: @yuk: The main diagonal of the distance matrix will always be zeroes, whether the graph is directed or not. Thanks everybody for the help, I will look into this in couple hours and dictate the solution that worked for me.